# Chrome warning "[DOM] Password forms should have (optionally hidden) username fields for accessibility" in console even with hidden username field

Tags: google-chrome, autocomplete, hidden-field, password-recovery

When visiting the "reset password" route of my single-page app and looking at the Chrome browser console, I am greeted with the follwing warning:

> [DOM] Password forms should have (optionally hidden) username fields for accessibility: (More info: [goo.gl/9p2vKq](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/create-amazing-password-forms))

Helpfully, the html of the form in question is also printed to the console in the next line, and quite clearly *contains a hidden username field*:

```html
<form data-ember-action data-ember-action-436=​"436">​
  <div class=​"form-group">
    <label for=​"newpasswordone">​Password​</label>​
    <input type=​"password" autocomplete=​"new-password" placeholder=​"Enter your new password" id=​"ember437" class=​"form-control ember-text-field ember-view" data-op-id=​"0">​
    <label for=​"newpasswordtwo">​Password (again)​</label>
    ​<input type=​"password" autocomplete=​"new-password" placeholder=​"Re-enter your new password" id=​"ember438" class=​"form-control ember-text-field ember-view" data-op-id=​"1">​
    <input type=​"hidden" name=​"username" autocomplete=​"username" value=​"a_b">
  ​</div>​
  <button disabled type=​"submit" class=​"btn btn-default">​Reset password​</button>​​
</form>​
```

I tried some minor variations -- unhiding the username field, marking it readonly, moving it outside the `div` -- without affecting the warning.
How does Chrome expect to be served the username?

*Problem occurs with Chrome 63 and 64.*

Comment: Similar but for angular: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48536209/google-chrome-warning-password-forms-should-have-optionally-hidden-username-f?rq=1

Answer (score 54):

I had the same problem. After some digging, I found that it needs to be an `input` element with the type `text`. By "optionally hidden" they mean that you may hide it with CSS.

If you just add an `input` with the name `email` or `username` chrome gives you another warning saying that `input` elements should have autocomplete attributes. So this is what I came up with to fix these errors:

```html
<input
  type="text"
  name="email"
  value="..."
  autocomplete="username email"
  style="display: none;"
>
```

You will need to manually render the actual username or email into the elements value attribute.

Also, keep in mind that inline styles are not a very good practice.

Comment: Thanks. Sounds plausible enough, but unfortunately, changing the input type to text (or even "username") did not change the warning message (except for the reproduced html node content, of course), even when I do not hide the field. :-(

Comment: I do have such field in my form and even it is not hidden at the moment and still getting this error :/ https://i.postimg.cc/7Z81vcgD/Screenshot-at-Apr-26-14-41-29.png

Comment: I'm not familiar with VueJS. I could imagine that the analyzer runs before the code is executed that renders the form field. Have you tried compiling the project and see if the warning is still there?

Comment: Using an input with type="text" and having it visually hidden appears to work (Chrome 91) insofar as the inbuilt password manager prompts to save the password along with the correct username, but note that the warning still appears in the console. It seems that Chrome shows the warning as general advice for any password reset form regardless of whether it actually contains a username field.

Comment: Thx! Just what I needed.

Comment: My form is a password reset form. It doesn't have and doesn't need any "username" input. Reset request is identified by unique token. Littering form's HTML with useless inputs "for accessibility" (huh?) seems nonsensical. Or am I missing something important here?

Comment: @silverdr Chrome and other browsers offer to create complex passwords on forms and without the username it can't save it to its password list. so adding the hidden username field gives the browser context for what to input on the login page

Comment: @Sarfaraaz - thank you, that seems to make some sense but if I understand it correctly then I'd need not only to provide a hidden input but also to pre-fill it with correct username. As I mentioned I don't currently have username available. Should be able to get it though.

Answer (score 25):

Use the `hidden` attribute instead of `type="hidden"`

```html
<input hidden type="text" autocomplete="username" value="{{...}}">
```

Answer (score 6):

I had this same situation.
Everything seemed be ok but I still got this verbose.

On my case helped me a relocate this userName input from end of form to begin of that.

It was my code before my changes:

```
<form id="changePass">
    <div class='modal-dialog'>
       <input type="password" class="form-control" id = "changePasswordOldPassword" autocomplete="current-password"/>
       <input type="password" class="form-control" id = "changePasswordNewPassword" autocomplete="new-password"/>
       <input type="password" class="form-control" id = "changePasswordNewPassword2" autocomplete="new-password"/>

       <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" id="change-password-ok-button">Ok</button>
          <button type ="button" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
       </div>
   </div>
   <input id="userName" name="username" autocomplete="username" value="">
</form>
```

And this is current code:

```
<form id="changePass">
   <input id="userName" name="username" autocomplete="username" value="">
   <div class='modal-dialog'>
       <input type="password" class="form-control" id = "changePasswordOldPassword" autocomplete="current-password"/>
       <input type="password" class="form-control" id = "changePasswordNewPassword" autocomplete="new-password"/>
       <input type="password" class="form-control" id = "changePasswordNewPassword2" autocomplete="new-password"/>

       <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" id="change-password-ok-button">Ok</button>
          <button type ="button" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
       </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Moving the hidden field to the top of the form removed the warning for me.

Comment: THANKS evolross, adding the username field after password has no meaning, username to be before pwd field

Answer (score 1):

you must put the input tag inside another tag for example:

```
  <form action="">
<div>
  <input type="text" autocomplete="username">
</div>
<div>
  <input type="password" autocomplete="password">
</div>
<div>
  <input type="password" autocomplete="password">
</div>
```

I had this same situation in VueJs when i use rendering conditional v-if v-else and i try put input tag inside new  tag and it's work for me

Comment: Worked like a charm, just wrap it in a <form>


You might encounter another error after mentioning inputs should have an autocomplete function - just add autoComplete="off" or "on" if that's what you prefer to your input

Answer (score 1):

Though I know that this question is quite old but thought maybe it may be useful for someone .I also faced the same issue with my React app update user password and this worked for me just above the password fields without label.Excuse me for writing the React way .

```html
<input hidden type='text' name='email' autoComplete='email' />
```

Basic usage :-

```html
<form>
 <input hidden type='text' name='email' autoComplete='email' />
 <label htmlFor="oldPass">Enter your current password</label>
 <input id="oldPass" type="password" />
 <label htmlFor="newPass">Enter your new password</label>
 <input id="newPass" type="password" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading [Jonas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5810492/jonas) comment I rebuilt the project and the warning went away

Answer (score 0):

I played around with the most recent version of Chrome (September 2023), and I needed elements of several of the individual answers to get the warning to go away:

- Hidden element had to be at the top, not the bottom
- It had to be `type="text"`; in my case I added the `hidden` attribute and it worked (didn't try the hidden styling)
- It had to have `autocomplete="username"`

Any one of the above missing and I got the warning.

Answer (score 0):

There is another thing about this warning: The username field MUST come before the password fields. If I render the username field after the password fields, the message stays.

This worked for me, if correctly positioned:

```html
<input type="text" name="username" autocomplete="username" style="display: none;"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same warning showing in the console and this is how I fixed it:

```html
<input hidden autocomplete="username" name="username" type="text" value="{{..}}"/>
<input hidden autocomplete="email" name="email" type="text" value="{{..}}"/>
```