# Google Chrome warning: Password forms should have (optionally hidden) username fields for accessibility

Tags: html, angular, forms, google-chrome

When visiting the "reset password" route of my single-page app and looking at the Chrome browser console, I am greeted with the following warning:

[DOM] Password forms should have (optionally hidden) username fields for accessibility: (More info: goo.gl/9p2vKq)

```html
<form class="searchAccount_form animated fadeIn form-tabular ng-pristine ng-valid ng-scope ng-hide" ng-show="isSet(6)" aria-hidden="true">
     <h5>Choose a new password</h5>
     <hr class="mt-0">
     <p>A strong password is a combination of letters and punctuation marks. It must be at least 6 characters long.</p>
     <div class="form-group row">
      <label class="col-form-label col-4">New Password</label>
      <div class="col-7">
       <input autocomplete="new-password" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty" type="password" ng-model="$parent.new_pass" name="password" ng-attr-type="{{ showPassword ? 'text':'password'}}" aria-invalid="false">
        </div>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
        <input type="hidden" name="username" value="craig.francis" autocomplete="off" readonly="readonly">
       <input type="hidden" name="csrf" value="tr6Gj6w6LczH98" autocomplete="off">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" name="button" ng-click="reset_password()">Continue</button>
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" name="button" ng-click="setTab(2)">Skip</button>
     </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 5):

If your question is about getting rid of this warning, you may add a hidden text-box as mentioned in the warning message.

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="username" ng-hide="true">
```

Comment: i tried adding a hidden input like this.

`<input type="hidden" name="username" value="name" autocomplete="username" readonly="readonly" />`

but the error is still there.

Comment: U can't use `<input type="hidden">`, need to use `<input type="text">` and hide it with `ng-hide`

Comment: `<input type="text" autocomplete="username" ng-hide="true">` 
it is not working

Comment: Have you kept the code inside the element `<div class="form-group">`?

Comment: Yes i used it inside and outside `<div class="form-group">`

Comment: @MrinalJain - You may keep it inside <div class="col-7">. See this [pen](https://codepen.io/gibinealias/pen/rJOVOy?editors=1001). Please let me know if this works.

Answer (score 2):

You should add `text` or `email` input type with `autocomplete="username"` attribute **before** all password inputs.  It can be `disabled` or `readonly`.

```
<form method="post">
<input type="text" autocomplete="username" value="{{username}}">
or
<input type="email" autocomplete="username email" value="{{username}}">
<input type="password" name="password">
</form>
```